# Repository is growing at rapid rate at some point - I have no idea why

Tags: adobe, aem, jcr

At some point, we see a HUGE increase of the diskspace occupied by AEM's repository. This usually occurs when Google Search Engine is visiting the site.

At this point, we have no idea at all why this is happening. We do see quite a lot of hits from GSE.

When the Tar PM Optimization is ran, the diskspace occupied is being freed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

he linkchecker creates these nodes when checking the validity of the links in your website. But, due to the nature of TAR storage, the nodes are not deleted on disk. This is only done during the Tar PM Optimization. That's why you see the diskspace is only freed up after running the optimization.

[Also see this link](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/performancetuningtips.html#TIP11%20%22Documentation)